# how to get multiple checkbox value in struts 2 using checkbox list

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts2, struts-config

Hi I am new to struts 2 ,
Can somebody tell me how to get multiple checkbox value in struts 2.
So far i have developed the code which is as follows.
i am getting the error

```
tag 'checkboxlist', field 'list', name 'subscribe': The requested list key 'subscription' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:333)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:875)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:523)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at jsp_servlet.__step1._jsp__tag6(__step1.java:371)
    at jsp_servlet.__step1._jsp__tag0(__step1.java:148)
    at jsp_servlet.__step1._jspService(__step1.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
```

My jsp page to get the values is

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

 <table class="profiletable" align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="center"><h2>Upload User Profile</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><s:form action="upload" method="post">
<s:textfield name="fname" label="First Name"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="lname" label="Last Name"></s:textfield>
<s:radio name="mstatus" label="Martial Status" list="{'Single','Married'}"></s:radio>
<s:radio name="gender" label="Gender" list="{'male','female'}"></s:radio>
<s:select list="{'India','USA','UK','Germany','France','Australia'}" label="Country" name="country"></s:select>
 <s:checkboxlist label="Letter you want to subscribe" name="subscribe" list="subscription" />
  <s:submit value="upload profile" align="center"></s:submit>
</s:form></td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

my jsp page to show the values is

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="p" %>
<h2>Profile uploaded sucessfully</h2>
 First Name:<p:property value="fname"/><br/>
Last Name:<p:property value="lname"/><br/>
Martial status:<p:property value="mstatus"/><br/>
Gender:<p:property value="gender"/><br/>
Country:<p:property value="country"/><br/>
Letters Subscribed:<p:property value="subscribe"/>/>
```

my action file is

```
package com.javapoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;



 public class UploadProfile extends ActionSupport {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String mstatus;
private String gender;
private String country;
private String subscribe;
private List<String> subscription;

public String getFname() {
    System.out.println("inside getfname");
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    System.out.println("inside getfname");
    System.out.println("the firstname set is "+fname);
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {

    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
    System.out.println("the lastname set is "+ lname);
}
public String getMstatus() {
    return mstatus;
}
public void setMstatus(String mstatus) {
    this.mstatus = mstatus;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getSubscribe() {
    return subscribe;
}
public void setSubscribe(String subscribe) {
    this.subscribe = subscribe;
}
public List<String> getSubscription() {
    return subscription;
}
public void setSubscription(List<String> subscription) {
    this.subscription = subscription;
}
public UploadProfile(){
    subscription=new ArrayList<String>();
    subscription.add("Politics");
    subscription.add("Sports");
    subscription.add("Editorial");
    subscription.add("Gadgets");
    subscription.add("Overdrive");
}
public String execute()throws Exception{
    System.out.println("inside execute");
    if(fname!=null){
    return "profileuploaded";
    }else{
        return "error";

    }
}

public String display(){

    return NONE;
}


}
```

My struts.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<action name="product" class="com.javapoint.Product">
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="upload" class="com.javapoint.UploadProfile">
<result name="profileuploaded">ProfileUploaded.jsp</result>
 <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
  </struts>
```

and my web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
 </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>step1.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. struts.xml:

`<action name="subscription_listing" method="UploadProfile" class="com.javapoint.UploadProfile" >
<result name="none">/your_jsppage_where_you_have_checkboxlist</result> 
</action>`

2.in Uploadprofile Action class modified Uploadprofile method:

```
public String UploadProfile(){
subscription=new ArrayList<String>();
subscription.add("Politics");
subscription.add("Sports");
subscription.add("Editorial");
subscription.add("Gadgets");
subscription.add("Overdrive");
return NONE;
```

}

[3]. Now Directly call subscription_listing action.

Do you got it?

Comment: hi jay,

how to perform step3

Comment: In url:whatever_your_path/subscription_listing.action

".action" postfix is optional.

Comment: @user251287 : Means in url instead of your jsp page call this action. Are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: hi jay,

calling it directly displays the start up page(step1.jsp) correctly but still while submitting the values it doesnt capture the checkbox value

also can you please tell me what is meant by return none

Comment: hi jay,
I am getting nullpointer exception when i tried to print the options selected

Comment: I don't get it. Can you tell the flow of pages with action.(means what you want to call first jsp page or action) and please mention name of each files.

Comment: i want to show step1.jsp after making the selection i want to show the selected form values on profileuploaded.jsp

earlier my flow without checkbox is

step1.jsp welcome page then
action UploadProfile.java
then it shows profileuploaded.jsp

only with the checkbox i am facing the problem, i am not able to call step1.jsp directly the error is Illustrated above.

Are you getting me?

Comment: there is two way: 1. you call action instead of jsp page
2. In your jsp page make an ajax call to "subscription_listing" action.

If you choose way-2 then you can call jsp page(Don't need to call listing action).

Comment: What is your problem? In displaying checkbox list on your step1.jsp or fetching values of selected value of checkboxlist on profileuploaded.jsp? Can you explain?

Comment: if i calls step1.jsp as my first page then it displays the page but without checkboxes and their labels.

Comment: So instead of calling step1.jsp call subscription_listing as per code that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to Struts2 hopefully this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/) will help you working with multiple checkbox in struts2

Comment: hi Dev,
I have used the same example earlier and made my prog exactly the same still getting the error.

Comment: @user251287, probably you are getting null list and thus exception.

Comment: @user251287 I have used your code in a demo application. I just returned "profileuploaded" from method execute and page is displaying fine with multiple checkbox.

Comment: Also i think that the class for action name "product" should be "com.javapoint.UploadProfile"

Comment: hi Dev,
action name product is for another page in my project.it has no link with this upload profile.

Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After surfing and implementing the above sugesstion ,I have come to solution that call the action file directly in case of chekbox,although there can be alternates but as of now i am unaware of it.

the problem is with my struts.xml it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts
 Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
 <struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

 <action name="upload" class="com.javapoint.UploadProfile">
 <result name="profileuploaded">ProfileUploaded.jsp</result>
  <result name="error">index.jsp</result>


 </action>
<action name="UploadProfile" class="com.javapoint.UploadProfile" method="display">
    <result name="none">/step1.jsp</result>
   </action>

</package>
</struts>
```

and the final action file is

package com.javapoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UploadProfile extends ActionSupport {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String mstatus;
private String gender;
private String country;
private String[] defaultsubscription;
private String[] yoursubscription;
private List<String> subscription;

public String getFname() {
    System.out.println("inside getfname");
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    System.out.println("inside getfname");
    System.out.println("the firstname set is "+fname);
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {

    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
    System.out.println("the lastname set is "+ lname);
}
public String getMstatus() {
    return mstatus;
}
public void setMstatus(String mstatus) {
    this.mstatus = mstatus;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
System.out.println(country);
}

public String[] getYoursubscription() {
    return yoursubscription;
}
public void setYoursubscription(String[] yoursubscription) {
    this.yoursubscription = yoursubscription;
}


public UploadProfile(){
    System.out.println("inside constructor");
    subscription=new ArrayList<String>();
    subscription.add("Politics");
    subscription.add("Sports");
    subscription.add("Editorial");
    subscription.add("Gadgets");
    subscription.add("Overdrive");
    }

public String[] getDefaultSubscription(){
    return new String [] {"Politics", "Sports"};
}
public List<String> getSubscription() {
    return subscription;
}
public void setSubscription(List<String> subscription) {
    this.subscription = subscription;
}


public String execute()throws Exception{
    System.out.println("inside execute");
    System.out.println(yoursubscription.toString()+"   "+subscription+"    "+defaultsubscription);
    if(fname!=null){
    return "profileuploaded";
    }else{
        return "error";

    }
}
public String display() {
    return NONE;
}



}
```