# checkboxlist preselected values struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, action, checkboxlist

i read some tutorials and other questions, but my checkboxlist is just not "checked".

My checkboxlist contains keyword objects. they are stores in an publication.

```
<s:checkboxlist list="keywords"  value="publication.keyword.keyID" listKey="keyID" listTitle="name" listValue="name" key="publication.keyword.keyID"/>
```

and here is where they get selected

```
<s:checkboxlist list="keywords"  listKey="keyID" listTitle="name" listValue="name" key="publication.keyword.keyID"/>
```

If i step through it with my debugger I am able to fill the keyword field in the action.

So whats wrong :(  ?

Comment: Just write some logic in `value` attribute. E.g. `list.contains(something)`.

Comment: what's the problem ? Are you unable to select them in the GUI/browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740444/how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-value-in-struts-2-using-checkbox-list) ?

Also as per [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/) source the values are comma separated.

Perhaps an iterator and plain checkbox would be a better approach. Then you can use [`fieldValue`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Checkbox.html) attribute.